# How do you reset Git credentials in Theia?

Tags: git, credentials, theia

First of all, this is running on Linux so forget about the Credential Manager from Windows.

By mistake I deployed a Theia IDE Docker container with my own Git credentials saved in it, which should belong to an another user. How do I reset the credentials?

I tried deleting it from /home/theia/.git-credentials but that brought nothing, because it still keeps on using my credentials.

Yes, I did use a command to save my credentials beforehand.

This is not a security issue for me per se, but rather an inconvenance, because my pushes from other users still show my name even though they were changed using

```
git config --global user.email "example@example.com"

git config --global user.name "[THEIA] Firstname Lastname"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First of all, this is running on Linux so forget about the Credential Manager from Windows.

Well... there still is [`microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Mac-and-Linux`](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Mac-and-Linux)

And if you are talking about the author associated to commits, that would not have anything to do with credentials anyway, only with `user.name/user.email`.
You would need to change the [author of those commits first](https://makandracards.com/makandra/1717-git-change-author-of-a-commit) and then force push.

The [OP munchkin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12360035/munchkin) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62026136/how-do-you-reset-git-credentials-in-theia/62036407?noredirect=1#comment109768312_62036407):

> he credentials expired just as I wanted to test this.
>   So that is solved, I guess, by doing nothing.

Comment: Well the credentials expired just as I wanted to test this. So that is solved I guess by doing nothing :D

Comment: @Munchkin Good point, and thank you for the feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.